# How to see that $A = A^{-1}$ and $A^2 = A$ as quick and easy as possible without computer aid

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm wondering which are the quickest/easiest methods to identify that the following relations hold for any given matrix:
$A = A^{-1}$ and $A^2 = A$

On a computer it's easy and quick to identify if this is the case by simply running the above operations to see if the equalities hold, however if you are using pen and paper this is perhaps not the easiest/quickest way anymore?

In special cases, does the same apply?:

- Householder Reflection
- Symmetric matrices

Comment: If $A^2 = A$ and $A$ is invertible (which it is when you demand $A = A^{-1}$) then $A^{-1}A^2 = A^{-1}A\implies A = I$ the identity matrix.

Comment: That's nice, but in this way you've gotta run those matrix multiplications.
So A = I for all cases? Or well, it's rather easy to see that A is the I matrix. So I guess this is a special case which applies to I matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$ where $\lambda $ is the characteristic polynomial. Then you have that by the Cayley Hamilton theorem.

Comment: So this is the most recommended and easiest method?